# How to change default view path in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to do multi theme in advanced-yii2.
I tried a lot of way for this but it doesn't work I can't understand.
Firstly, I added this to "frontend/config/main.php";

```
          'view' => [
              'theme' => [
                 'pathMap' => [ 
                    '@app/views' => [ 
                        '@webroot/themes/demo/views',

                     ]
                 ],
               ],
            ],
```

and it doesn't work, then I tried to creating a new view class for frontend, for example:

```
    namespace frontend\components;

class NewsView extends \yii\web\View {

    function init() {
    \Yii::$app->view->viewPath = '@webroot/themes';
    parent::init();
    }

}
```

and added in config.php

```
'view' => [
        'class' => 'frontend\components\NewsView',
```

but it doesn't work too.

What should I do?

Comment: I solved, I forgot this is my wrong, while SiteController is working to render to "index.tpl",there don't have "index.tpl". :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can redefine getViewPath method at your base controller. Like

```
public function getViewPath()
{
    return Yii::getAlias('@frontend/views/newview');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a controller you can change the view path also in the init method:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->viewPath = '@frontend/views/newview'; // or before init()
}
```

Or use the already [suggested way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29372088/57091).

---

Hint for idiots like me: **Don't try** to override the [`$viewPath`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#$viewPath-detail) property.

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public $viewPath = '@frontend/views/newview'; // Doesn't work
}
```

This won't work. Actually the private member [`$_viewPath`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L70) needs to be set in the base controller! It will be evaluated on rendering (if parameter [`$view`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#render()-detail) is a relative path). `$this->viewPath = '...';` calls a setter function which sets `$_viewPath`. If you override `$viewPath` with `public $viewPath = '...';` calling the magic setter function is not possible anymore, thus `$_viewPath` will not be changed.