# Yii2 advanced change views default path (theming)

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, theming

I would like for my application to automatically change template
so i created this structure frontend/web/themes/myTheme
following http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html i added this code in frontend/config/main.php

```
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@app/themes/myTheme',
                'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/myTheme',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => '@app/themes/myTheme',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

however i kept getting the error that " /var/www/html/myProject/app/frontend/views/site/index.php" The view file does not exist???

i also tried to put this function inside the controller based on [How to change default view path in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028712/how-to-change-default-view-path-in-yii2)

```
public function getViewPath()
{
    return Yii::getAlias('@web/themes/myTheme/site');
}
```

so my question is:
    1. how can I change the views default path?
    2. how can i do it automatically since i can not change the common/config/main.php settings during a session?

site controller

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ProductSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your controller?

Comment: simple controller

Answer (score 1):

I think you are configuring the wrong file.Don't configure themes in the common/config
Try this:
in **frontend/config/main.php**

```
'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@frontend/views'=>'@frontend/themes/myTheme',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

if you need to configure the backend then in the **backend/config/main.php**

```
'components' => [
            'view' => [
                'theme' => [
                    'pathMap' => [
                        '@backend/views'=>'@backend/themes/myTheme',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

The *common* folder is has to contain the files that are required by both 
frontend and backend.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i actually used frontend not common

Answer (score 0):

First question:

I think than you have a common mistake in yii when used advanced app: the alias @app references root directory of **frontend**, **backend**, or **common** depending on where you access it from [View documentation here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/).
You would used the solution proposed by ovicko.

Second question:

You can change the theme configuration dynamically in controller through view object:

```
 $this->view->theme->pathMap =['@app/views' => '@app/themes/myTheme/',];
```

**EDIT**
According to [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html):

> Theming is a way to replace a set of views with another without the need of touching the original view rendering code.

What means that the original view file **must** exist and theming simply replace it in during rendering. So you must create a file in  /var/www/html/myProject/app/frontend/views/site/index.php (a empty file is valid) in order to theming works. 
This sounds quite ridiculous, I Know, but it works.

But I think that is much better and easier the use of [differents layouts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts), again, to change dinamically the layout in your controller:

```
 $this->layout = 'route/yourlayout';
```

Comment: I had a problem using apps with gii to generate files so I prefer to use the folder names instead .

Comment: Ayes, me too. It's much better and less confusing use folder name. Specially if you have a project with four or more route folder.